# Problems with counting in text

Tags: php, html

I have a problem when trying to count in PHP using a button and a text file to save it. I can't see the problem in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="p">Click here</div>
   <div id="results"></div>
<script>
$('#p').click(function()
{
   $('#results').load("count.php");
});
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

count.php contains the following:

```
    <?php

    $clicks = file_get_contents("clicks.txt");
    $clicks++;

        $fp = fopen("clicks.txt", "w+");
        fwrite($fp, $clicks);
        fclose($fp);

//give the count to the user
echo "result: $clicks";

    ?>
```

Comment: Wow. Any reason your are doing this via PHP and not just JavaScript?

Comment: @iambriansreed Seems like a better idea. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @silly The thing is that when I click the button, nothing happens. I can't locate the problem.

Comment: This seems like a good exercise on basic AJAX.

Comment: did you chmod 0777 `clicks.txt` ?

Comment: I created the `clicks.txt`, I checked the call for the click thingy.

Comment: first of all... install firebug or another web developer plugin for you browser... you can see the ajax request and more!

Comment: `$('#result')` Should be `$('#results')` :) - Added a no PHP answer below. :)

Comment: does the click count need to be remembered acrossed multiple sessions / instances? or is this just a *you've clicked this N times since you visited the page*

Comment: @rlemon It must be remembered in a text file on my FTP server. And everyone can increase the value of it and view the value.

Comment: @user1431627 Ok, see my answer, This works locally for me. If you need  help with permissions on your server I would need to know a little more about how it is setup and how you are accessing it (ssh, ftp, cpanel?)

Comment: @iambriansreed He nailed it. Plus `chmod 777` the .txt file. Works on my end. So... is this a replacement for morning `java`? On to my regular cup ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the OP it looks like you want this data to be retained and accumulate for all users, so a server side component is necessary.

Here is my take on it:
HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <div id="p">Click here</div>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script>
    $('#p').click(function()
    {
        $.ajax("count.php", {
                complete: function(jqXHR, status) {
                    $("#results").text(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            })
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
   $clicks = intval(file_get_contents("clicks.txt"));
    $clicks++;

        $fp = fopen("clicks.txt", "w+");
        fwrite($fp, $clicks);
        fclose($fp);

//give the count to the user
echo "result: $clicks";
```

notice the php is the same but I now change the $clicks value to an integer after I get it from the file.

You also need to ensure the files are read/write for the server... in linux you would just do this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

to make your `www/` directory (or change it to the directory your Apache(?) server uses..) read/writeable by the server (this may be overkill, you can target specific files using the same method, just remove the `-R` (recursive) flag).

I tested this setup locally and it works for me, goodluck!

Edit: Just being nice....

Here is a no-jQuery solution to the JS (this won't work in all browsers, specifically older IE versions, I'll let you handle these :P )

```
var p_btn = document.getElementById('p'),
    results = document.getElementById('results');
p_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET','count.php',false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 ) {
            while(results.hasChildNodes()) {
                results.removeChild(results.lastChild);
            }
            results.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText));
        }
    }
    xhr.send();

}, false);
// enjoy!
```

## [Live Demo](http://rlemon.net63.net/)

*Ignore the add code that gets spit back out from the server.... damn free hosts*

Comment: I didn't use .load() because frankly I couldn't get it working on my localhost. $.ajax worked fine however.

Comment: Can I use this without jQuery?

Comment: yes but you would need to write your own XHR (ajax) functions.

Comment: This one works well, and you don't have to create the .txt file yourself, the server will take care of everything for you. Great job, cheers~

Comment: @user1426486 Last update: Here is your simplified no jQuery Javascript solution. I hope you can extract what you need.

Comment: This is really wierd because both of you say this works and it dose not for me. This is really confusing why it's not working.

Comment: Because your clicks.txt file or your web directory is not writable by www-data (apache) - What OS/Server technology are you using?

Comment: No. I only use BBEdit and my service provider is Statlogic.

Comment: (I am a newbie when it comes to servers, PHP etc) Should I use it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12557/discussion-between-user1431627-and-rlemon)